# std::thread::hardware_concurrency and static initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static, static-order-fiasco

May this global function suffer from static initialization fiasco?

```
template <typename TFn>
void ParallelFor(int iIni,int iFin,TFn Fn)    
{
  static const unsigned int NThread= std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  // ...    
}
```

Comment: Unrelated nitpick: note that your NThread variable will exist for each distinct instantiation of the function template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> May this global function suffer from static initialization fiasco?

No, it wouldn't. You are safe... :-)

Quoting the C++ standard draft (emphasis mine)...

> [$6.7: 4:](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.dcl#4) **Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with
>   static storage duration** ([basic.stc.static]) **or thread storage
>   duration** ([basic.stc.thread]) **is performed the first time control
>   passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered
>   initialized upon the completion of its initialization.** If the
>   initialization exits by throwing an exception, the initialization is
>   not complete, so it will be tried again the next time control enters
>   the declaration. **If control enters the declaration concurrently
>   while the variable is being initialized, the concurrent execution
>   shall wait for completion of the initialization**

Also, see: [Static local variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables)

Since your function is a function template `template <typename TFn>`, for each separate instantiation (substitution of `TFn`), `static const unsigned int NThread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();` will be evaluated

Comment: Cool. But what if the function is instantiated in the constructor of a static object ([link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order))?

Comment: @metalfox, to your question: there wouldn't be any problem still! Remember, your static variable is in a *function block scope*. It is guaranteed to be initialized first time it is called at runtime by **whosoever**. (Reread the quoted paragraph). Your link deals with a different scenario i.e when the objects are in *global scope*: in that case your answer is in the [next section](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use)

Comment: @WhiZTiM. Thanks for your detailed answer. What I was worried about is that some implementation of `hardware_concurrency` might rely on a global/static variable, thus producing the fiasco. From your comments I deduce that it is either not possible or explicitly forbidden by the Standard.